# How to use `this` in react-native-collapsible accordion component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-collapsible

I have a react-native screen, where I want to use react-native-collapsible accordion component to show a list of assets. In the required `rendercontent` prop of accordion, I pass in a function `sellAsset` defined inside the screen component where I use `this` keyword to refer to the screen component. But it didn't work, always telling me `this.sellAsset is not a function`. Please see the code below.

Tried some function binding but didn't work. It seems the `this` passed to the accordion component does not point to the screen component.

So how to call `this.sellAsset` correctly?

```
renderContent(item) {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.imageContent]}>
          <View style={[styles.detailContainer, {paddingVertical: 0}]}>
            <Image source={getImage(_.get(item, ['Asset', 'image']))} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.assetImage}/>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.priceContainer}>
            <CustomSignInButton
                text="SELL"
                onPress={() => {this.sellAsset();}}
                buttonBackgroundColor="transparent"
                buttonBorderColor="white"
                buttonTextColor="white"
                buttonHeight={30}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }

render() {
    return (
        <LinearGradient colors={[Colors.splashGradient.top, Colors.splashGradient.middle, Colors.splashGradient.bottom]}
                        style={{flex: 1}}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <IOSStatusBar backgroundColor="transparent"/>
            {this.state.transactionDetails !== null ?
                (this.state.transactionDetails.length > 0 &&
                    <Accordion sections={this.state.transactionDetails} renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
                               renderContent={this.renderContent} underlayColor={Colors.rowSeparatorBlue}
                    />
                ) : <View/>
            }
          </View>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `onPress={() => this.sellAsset()}` or `onPress={this.sellAsset}`, but you probably know. Can you share `sellAsset()` function definition?

Comment: @Milore Thanks for your answer. It was the `this` binding problem and fixed it in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly sellAsset() is a method on your screen component?

You have two options:

**1. Bind both methods to this**

```
class YourScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.renderContent = this.renderContent.bind(this);
    this.sellAsset = this.sellAsset.bind(this);
  }

  sellAsset() { ... }

  renderContent() { ... }
}
```

**2. Use arrow functions**

```
class YourScreen extends React.Component {

  sellAsset = () => { ... }

  renderContent = (item) => { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem. It turned out I didn't bind those methods in the constructor, many thanks!